# Remove specific character in position if len > 10 power query editor

Tags: powerquery

Using Power Query Editor I am trying to remove the (Right,3) character if the LEN of the string is > 11.

This is what I am working with now  ' = Table.RenameColumns(#"Merged Columns",{{"Merged", "oe_nosuf"}})'

example of current value : "65507129-02"
If the value is "65507129-002" then I want to remove the extra "0" from the right 3 spaces.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample two ways to do this, a new column based on Column1 or replacing the current value of Column1

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if Text.Length([Column1]) = 12 then Text.Start([Column1],9) & Text.End([Column1],2) else [Column1]),
#"Modify" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Column1", each if Text.Length(_) = 12 then Text.Start(_,9) & Text.End(_,2) else _ , type text}})
in  #"Modify"
```